# Django secretballot and rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Does anybody know `secretballot` plugin for voting?
I have a little problem with that, I don't know how can I connect field from `secretballot` to my model in `serializer`:

I have:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

secretballot.enable_voting_on(Test)
```

and in shell, command:

```
x = Test.objects.get(pk=1)
x.total_upvotes
```

works fine, returning 0. But in my API

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = (
            "id", "name", "total_upvotes"
        )
```

gives me:

> Field name `total_upvotes` is not valid for model `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `total_upvotes` is calculated value. If that's the case then you need to add custom serializer field.

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    total_upvotes = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        # as it was..
```